# Pointers Not Reflecting Change when value changed in a function

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I am implementing a Linked List using an array.It has a function Reverse
defined below

```
void Reverse(List *l)
{
    List *m=CreateList(ListSize(l));
    for(int i=0;i<l->count;i++)
    {
        m->array[i]=l->array[l->count-i-1];
        m->count++;
    }
    free(l->array);
    free(l);
    l=m;
    //Traverse(l); Here it prints the reversed List

}
```

It takes a List structure as a argument. I am calling it from main like this

```
int main()
{
    size=5;
    List *l=CreateList(size);
    Reverse(l);
    Traverse(l); //Here the list is not printing the reversed list !

}
```

Why are the changes I made to l in reverse not showing up in main() ?
Thanks !

Comment: There is no such thing as pass by reference in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `l = m`, you are just setting `l` within `Reverse`. `l` is part of the argument list to `Reverse`. When you change the value, it only changes it for the duration of the call to `Reverse`. It never gets propagated to the caller.

You can use Filip's method to propagate the value.

Or, you can:

1. redefine `Reverse` as: `List *Reverse(List *l)`
2. add `return m` as the last statement in it
3. and call via: `l = Reverse(l)`.

But, this is a bit wasteful. You can also do an in-place reversal:

```
void Reverse(List *l)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = l->count - 1;

    // NOTE: this should be whatever the type of array[0] is:
    int tmp;

    for (;  left < right;  ++left, --right) {
        tmp = l->array[left];
        l->array[left] = l->array[right];
        l->array[right] = tmp;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> When I do *l=*m in the last line the code works but I dont know why !

Even that has a bug.

That is because you are replacing the entire *contents* of what `l` points to. Essentially, you created a new [reversed] list `m`, filled it, then copied it back to `l`.

Doing `free(l)` *before* doing `*l = *m` is a *bug*. You are dereferencing a pointer to freed memory.

You *do* want to do `free(l->array)`, but *not* `free(l)`.

Also, after doing `*l = *m`, you need to do `free(m)`. Otherwise, you have a memory leak on the `struct` that `m` points to [but *not* what `m->array` points to because it gets saved in `l->array`].

This is needless complexity and error prone.

And you did twice as much work as needed. When you do `*l = *m`, you are really doing:

```
l->count = m->count;
for (int i = 0;  i < m->count;  ++i)
    l->array[i] = m->array[i];
```

In other words, don't do the `*l = *m`, even if it seems to work. Use one of the three easier/correct ways.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> It seems to work fine though(*l=*m) even if the memory that l points to doesn't exist . Please tell me what does the function free() actually does in this case

Yes, it *seems* to work fine, but it does *not* work fine [in the general case].

After you do `free(l)`, what `l` pointed to is unavailable. The memory allocator assumes that you have *no* further use for this memory [because when you do `free(l)`, you are *telling* it so]. The allocator is at liberty to do *whatever* it wishes with that memory:

1. In a multithreaded environment, between the time you call `free(l)` and it returning control to you, another thread could have done a `malloc` and now you have two threads pointing to the same memory and using it for different purposes. Doing the subsequent `*l = *m` would corrupt the data that the *other* thread is storing there. This introduces a subtle, intermittent, hard to find bug.
2. In a single threaded environment, the memory allocator might use the memory to store metadata for its own [internal] purposes. Again, *before* it returns from `free(l)`. So, when you do `*l = *m`, you could be corrupting the allocator's internal data structures (or vice versa). The next time you issue a `malloc`, the allocator might segfault.
3. The next time you issue a `malloc`, it might return a pointer to the *same* memory that `l` is/was pointing to (e.g. you create a second list [in `main`] by calling `l2 = CreateList(10)`). Now, `l` and `l2` have the same value (i.e. they point to the same `struct`). So, instead of `l` and `l2` being separate lists, they *collide*. Or, `l2` might be different, but `l2->array` might overlap with `l`

Below is one example of a general resource allocation/release problem. Because you don't know what the allocate or release functions do internally, you can't be safe accessing *anything* inside the resource after it's been released/freed. The release function below adds one line to illustrate why it's unsafe to do what you did with `*l = *m`

```
#include <malloc.h>

struct resource {
    int count;
    int *array;
};

struct resource *
allocate_resource(int count)
{
    struct resource *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct resource));
    ptr->count = count;
    ptr->array = malloc(sizeof(int) * count);

    return ptr;
}

void
free_resource(struct resource *ptr)
{

    free(ptr->array);

    // prevents "*l = *m" from "seeming to work"
    ptr->array = NULL;

    free(ptr);
}

int
main(void)
{

    while (1) {
        struct resource *x = allocate_resource(20);

        // x may be utilized here ...

        free_resource(x);

        // x may _not_ be utilized here ...
        // this will segfault
        x->array[0] = 23;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I do *l=*m in the last line the code works but I dont know why !

Comment: It seems to work fine though(*l=*m) even if the memory that l points to doesn't exist . Please tell me what does the function free() actually does in this case !

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass a double pointer to be possible to change where does the pointer points.

```
void Reverse(List **l);
Reverse(&l);
```

---

Its not possible in C to pass by reference, from [www-cs-students.stanford.edu](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~sjac/c-to-cpp-info/references):

> In C, Pass-by-reference is simulated by passing the address of a
>   variable (a pointer) and dereferencing that address within the
>   function to read or write the actual variable. This will be referred
>   to as "C style pass-by-reference."

Comment: But In the reverse function when I traverse l,It gives the reversed list. That means the l is pointing at the same list as m !

Comment: Yes inside the function. But you have to use double pointer to be possible to reflect it in main. Just try it.

Comment: l is already a pointer to a list . I have edited the question .

Comment: Why is this happening...Please help !

Answer (score 1):

In C, function arguments are *always* passed by value. This means that in the function `ReverseList()` `l` is a *copy* of the pointer to `List` that was passed in the function call. So, when the reversed `List` is created, and the address is assigned to `l` within the function, this has no effect on the original pointer to `List` in `main()` (since `l` within `Reverse()` is only a copy of `l` within `main()`). It may help to give variables in functions names that are different from their corresponding names in callers to help keep this sort of thing straight.

One solution is to pass a pointer to pointer to `List` into the `Reverse()` function:

```
void Reverse(List **lptr)
{
    List *m=CreateList(ListSize(*lptr));
    for(int i=0;i<(*lptr)->count;i++)
    {
        m->array[i]=(*lptr)->array[(*lptr)->count-i-1];
        m->count++;
    }
    free((*lptr)->array);
    free(*lptr);
    *lptr=m;
    //Traverse(l); Here it prints the reversed List
}
```

Call this function with `Reverse(&l)`. Here, since a copy of a pointer to a pointer to `List` is used in `Reverse()`, and `lptr` points to the pointer `l` in `main()`, `lptr` can be dereferenced and the value of `m` can be assigned to the actual pointer to `List` (`l`) found in `main()`.

An alternative solution is to change the `Reverse()` function to return a pointer to `List` to the caller. Then the returned value is assigned to `l`:

```
List * Reverse(List *l)
{
    List *m=CreateList(ListSize(l));
    for(int i=0;i<l->count;i++)
    {
        m->array[i]=l->array[l->count-i-1];
        m->count++;
    }
    free(l->array);
    free(l);
    return m;
    //Traverse(l); Here it prints the reversed List
}

int main(void)
{
    size=5;
    List *l=CreateList(size);
    l = Reverse(l);
    Traverse(l); //Here the list is not printing the reversed list !

    return 0;
}
```

Also, if `CreateList()` is not already checking for allocation errors, the code should be checking for these before `free`ing the previous allocations.